# XML is not formatting correctly from object class

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-formatting

I want to generate the XML output from my object class as per below xml, But when it is creating the xml Node  **<ns2:LoadStatusData**  is creating as **<LoadStatusData** *( ns2: )* is missing from the XML. Can you please suggest what i am doing mistake in my object class.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns2:LoadStatusData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.3gtms.com/tms/v1/tns">
  <BatchInfo>
    <BatchNum>20230420175634</BatchNum>
    <BatchDateTime>2023-04-20T17:56:34.5647378+05:30</BatchDateTime>
    <SentBy>NIN-Integration</SentBy>
    <PageNum>0</PageNum>
    <PageCnt>0</PageCnt>
    <NullPrimaryEmptyElements>false</NullPrimaryEmptyElements>
  </BatchInfo>
</ns2:LoadStatusData>
```

For the same i have created object class as per below

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="BatchInfo")]
public class BatchInfo { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="BatchNum")] 
    public double BatchNum { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="BatchDateTime")] 
    public DateTime BatchDateTime { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="SentBy")] 
    public string SentBy { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="PageNum")] 
    public int PageNum { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="PageCnt")] 
    public int PageCnt { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="NullPrimaryEmptyElements")] 
    public bool NullPrimaryEmptyElements { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="LoadStatusData")]
public class LoadStatusData { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="BatchInfo")] 
    public BatchInfo BatchInfo { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsd")] 
    public string Xsd { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi")] 
    public string Xsi { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ns2")] 
    public string Ns2 { get; set; } 

    [XmlText] 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

Current XML is generating as below there (ns2:) is missing

```
<LoadStatusData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.3gtms.com/tms/v1/tns">
  <BatchInfo>
    <BatchNum>20230420181158</BatchNum>
    <BatchDateTime>2023-04-20T18:11:58.7330956+05:30</BatchDateTime>
    <SentBy>NIN-Integration</SentBy>
    <PageNum>0</PageNum>
    <PageCnt>0</PageCnt>
    <NullPrimaryEmptyElements>false</NullPrimaryEmptyElements>
  </BatchInfo>
</LoadStatusData>
```

Comment: [XmlRoot(ElementName="BatchInfo")] contains a namspace parameter : [XmlRoot(ElementName="BatchInfo", Namespace = "URL")]  You need to add the correct URL.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your reply but xml is missing ns2 before LoadStatusData

Comment: I just used BatchInfo as an example.  You need to add wherever it is missing.